# I'm a lvl10 sorcerer: should I plan for Spell Sniper + Eldritch Adept to get a powerful cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, sorcerer, eldritch-invocations

I'm currently a level 10 Tiefling Sorcerer, playing my first game of D&D (5e). I'm mostly selecting spells for boon'ing party members, with a couple of save-or-suck spells in reserve + simple damage output (e.g. Chaos Bolt + Fire Bolt). I'd quite like to have a more chunky Cantrip, e.g. Eldritch Blast, but I'd also like to hit level 20 Sorcerer, too. I already have the Observant and Ritual Caster feats, and 20 Charisma as a luck did have it when we rolled our characters, too.

Draft plan: Level 12 Spell Sniper (Eldritch Blast) + level 16 Eldritch Adept (Agonising Blast)

An artificer in our group is providing me with a [Mind Sharpener](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/artificer-infusions#toc9) set of robes, so I don't think Warcaster is necessary until potentially late game.

Thoughts, comments, shaming, critique?

Comment: Anyway, welcome to rpg.se! We have a [tour] and a [help] with lots of information. This question *is* largely opinion based, so it will likely be closed. However, there was a concrete, easy to point out issue with the build, so I left an answer anyway. Further feedback on your build ideas are better suited for a traditional forum, which we can recommend here: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449)

Comment: If you have question about rules interactions and feature interactions for a build, we can probably handle those.

Answer (score 12):

#### You can't take Agonizing Blast with Eldritch Adept unless you are a Warlock.

Eldritch Adept states:

> If the invocation *has a prerequisite of any kind*, you can choose that invocation only if you’re a warlock who meets the prerequisite.

Agonizing Blast has prerequisite:

> *Prerequisite: eldritch blast cantrip*

You have to take one level of Warlock to get Agonizing Blast via the feat. Even if the prerequisite itself doesn’t require being a warlock, Eldritch Adept requires you to have a level of warlock to take an invocation with *any kind* of prerequisite.

Comment: That is me being blind. Thank you for the clarification.